# Error executing child request

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a webpage which displays a customer's details called custdetails. The page can be reached succesfully by

*~/sites/myaccount/custdetails/?id=1234*

One of my classes uses the below code to get the details and get it into a Stringwriter

```
Dim CustDetailsUrl As String = "~/sites/myaccount/custdetails/?id=1234"
Dim sw As New StringWriter
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(CustDetailsUrl, sw)
```

C#

```
string CustDetailsUrl = "~/sites/myaccount/custdetails/?id=1234";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(CustDetailsUrl, sw);
```

When the last line is hit, i get the error

***System.Web.HttpException: Error executing child request for /sites/myaccount/custdetails/?id=1234***

Below is what i have tried to resolve

So i have changed the URL accordingly and can confirm the above URL is correct and reachable.

I have tried Response.Redirect using this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/320439/prb-error-executing-child-request-error-message-when-you-use-server.transfer-or-server.execute-in-asp.net-page but i dont think that applies as im expecting the StringWriter to return the contents of the page.

Added the line  to the config file

but none work. How could this be resolved?

Comment: Try this `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/sites/myaccount/custdetails","id=1234");` instead of `HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(CustDetailsUrl, sw);`

Comment: So how do i pass in the writer/use the writer to hold the details?

Comment: Use the above method and send the details of `StringWriter` as a query string to another page